# Timer/counter overflow and TIFR register

Tags: avr

I recently planned to use AVR timer/counter for my projects. I have studied a number of documents about how to set it up. I use ATTiny2313A to test it out and learn about its features. I came across a problem when tried to toggle a pin for every few seconds.

According to the datasheet the `TIFR` has the following bit arrangement:

[image]

As you see the first bit is assigned to `TOV0`. When a counter overflow occurs this bit is set to 1. I used this fact and developed a code as following:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
uint16_t count=0, M=500;
uint8_t n=0x02;
DDRB=0xff;
TCNT0=0x00;
TCCR0B=(1<<CS00) | (1<<CS02); //use prescaler 1024


   while (1)
   {
       while ((TIFR & n) == 0); // control passes this loop after TIFR sets to n,
                                   // which is when counter overflows

       TCNT0 = 0x00;
       TIFR=n; // clear TIFR
       count++;

       if (count>=M)
       {
           PORTB ^= (1 << PB0);
           count=0;
       }

return (0);
   }
```

The code works as expected. I expect that when an overflow occurs `TIFR` changes to `0x02` as `TOV0` sets to one. But that seems not to be the only scenario. If I change the variable `n` to something like `n=0x04` and build the program I see the same behavior, meaning that the LED connected to `PB0` still toggles with the same frequency as it did previously. The second bit in `TIFR` corresponds to `OCF0B`. So if the code wants to work as before this bit **must** change to 1 when an overflow happens. But does it? I don't think the output compare flag is enabled so `OCF0B` can't change.

Comment: "I expect that when an overflow occurs TIFR changes to 0x02" - Notice that `TIFR`, like many other registers, does not represent an 8-bit numerical value (0x00...0xff). It represents 8 (7) individual (somewhat independent) binary flags, each in one of the bits. Hence you always check for the bits you're interested in via `&` as you did, not for a change in the *register's* value.

Comment: The source code is broken (missing a `}`) and the indentation is horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OCF0B` is a compare match flag, which will get set regardless of whether the interrupt is enabled or not. It will get set exactly once per overflow cycle, just like a broken clock will show the correct time twice a day. This is why you are getting the exact same period time with this flag or with the overflow flag.